# Redux dev tools screen has become blank

Tags: react-redux, google-chrome-devtools

I was using redux dev tools and i was exploring it and on clicking on of the option by redux screen has become blank can anyone tell me what should to do to again see my states.

i was exploring it and on clicking on of the option by redux screen has become blank.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you need to do some works based on [redux-devtools](https://redux.js.org/usage/configuring-your-store#integrating-the-devtools-extension)

infact you have to do this:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import monitorReducersEnhancer from './enhancers/monitorReducers'
import loggerMiddleware from './middleware/logger'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  const middlewares = [loggerMiddleware, thunkMiddleware]
  const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)

  const enhancers = [middlewareEnhancer, monitorReducersEnhancer]
  const composedEnhancers = composeWithDevTools(...enhancers)

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancers)

  return store
}
```

you have to wrapp the enhancers with `composeWithDevTools` function.